# saving username password in option.html and loading them automatically

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have created 2 extensions for websites that i do not own and they do not have an api.

when you open the extension, there will be a login screen, but when you close it, you'll be logged out, i want to either save the cookies so when you reopen the extension you'll be logged in or to save the password like [lastpass](https://lastpass.com/index.php) and create an option page, but:

1- I do not want to host the database on my vps, coz i don't want to pay to maintain the extension if i have many users, and i don't want to keep protecting my database from hackers till death :)

2- I do not want to host it on any paid service

unfortunately, lastpass doesn't have an api, so i'm thinking of storing the username and password on the user's pc, and i do not care if he got hacked because it is his responsibility to keep his pc secured and not mine :) any idea or tutorial on how to do it?

and by the way the websites are created using .net framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store information between browser restarts in [localStorage](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-learning-about-html5-local-storage/).

Comment: I was wondering isn't better to save sessions? when you close google chrome extension your session will end and no one can hack you, and when you start google chrome you'll have to login...don't you think it's better?

Comment: I'm not an asp.net guy but i made 2 google extension for 2 asp.net websites, I used the same source code, one of them lost the session as soon as the iframe is closed and the other one works perfectly and maintain the session until the window is closed..since i cannot edit the source code of the websites i'm trying to force my extension :)

Comment: @Eli So you don't want the data to be stored between browser restarts? Then you can just store it inside background page's variable space `var username="..."`.